# XRDP oh no something went wrong log off redhat linux

Tags: rhel, gnome, xrdp

I have been using redhat linux server using xrdp, it was working and recently it stopped working with the following failure.

[image]

I was checking `xrdp-sesman -nm`.

the following is the error.

`flatpak: /home/username/anaconda3/lib/libuuid.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib64/libappstream-glib.so.8)`

I added `/lib64 and /usr/lib64 to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

how can i solve this issue?